# Folder that is impossible to delete, what else can I try?

Tags: windows-11

I have a folder on one of my drives that is impossible to delete or do anything with.

The full path is:

```
E:\Temp\y\xF12 Devastator (PE upg.
```

This is a folder leftover from when I was playing Empyrion, and originally held a blueprint for a ship I built in the game. I have since moved it to the Temp folder to at least not have a problem with the game.

I can rename and move around the `y` folder, but I can do nothing with the one inside.

Examples:

- Try delete from Windows Explorer:

  [image: delete file]
- Try `rd` from a command prompt, gives "The system cannot find the file specified." (yes, it says file, even if I use `rd`)
- Try `rd /s y` from outside of the `y` folder, gives `y\xF12 Devastator (PE upg. - The system cannot find the file specified.`
- Rebooting to troubleshoot menu, opening a command prompt, same errors
- `chkdsk e: /f`, does not fix it, gives `Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required`

So what else can I try? Except reformatting the entire disk, which is a hassle as the drive contains lots of data.

All of the commands above were executed with administrator rights by the way.

Comment: What if you delete TEMP itself?

Comment: Same error as trying to delete `y`.

Comment: do you use " " when trying rd or rmdir /s ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a folder on one of my drives that is impossible to delete or do
> anything with.

The files in the folder may have "No Locking Handle"  .  That is what I see from time to time.

Delete the files with Unlocker 1.9.2 (Major Geeks).   Works on all Windows systems up to and including Windows 11 22H2.

Once the files are deleted, the folder can be deleted.

There are other sources but be careful of other downloads. Unlocker 1.9.2 itself is fine.

If Unlocker causes issues (crashing), then the disk itself most likely has issues - could be temporary or actual hardware errors.

Comment: Unlocker crashed, but I found a different tips, I used `rd /s \\?\E:\Temp\y` and it worked. Though I'm a bit wary of the integrity of the file system on this disk, so I have started the process of moving stuff off of it, and going to do a reformat.

Comment: Unlocker is very reliable, so if it crashed there is a disk error..  I noted this in my answer

Comment: Yes, I realize that crashing unlocker could mean serious stuff. I have since replaced the disk entirely. I did try with and without quotes for all the commands.